# JSP can't find Package for import in NetBeans

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans, import, netbeans-8

I am creating a java web application in NetBeans and can't seem to import a Java file.

The issue is with welcome.jsp which is located at:
Web Pages -> WEB_INF -> welcome.jsp

I am trying to import FaqCategories.java located at:
Source Packages -> com.apress.faq -> FaqCategories.java

I have the following code in welcome.jsp

```
<%@ page errorPage="/WEB-INF/errorPage.jsp"
     import="java.util.Iterator,com.apress.faq.FaqCategories" %>
```

The error I keep getting is that "package com.apress.faq does not exist". But it does, and I have verified that the spelling is correct. My first thought was that the java package needed to be moved from "Source Packages" to "Web Pages" or "WEB-INF", but I can't create a package with the name "com.apress.faq" because it already exists.

Do I need to do something differently if I am importing from a different folder ("Source Packages" instead of "Web Pages")? Or am I going about the import wrong?

EDIT: Added Screenshot. Shows Project structure, and "welcome.jsp" is displayed with with error highlighted.
[image]

Please let me know if more information is needed.

**Solution:** Needed to clean the project, NetBeans goofed. Once I did a clean and build the error went away.

Comment: Can we see your project structure?

Comment: Just don't use scriptlets in the first place.